# Running EC2Config after modifying an Elastic Beanstalk custom EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I am creating a custom AMI with Visual Studio C++ runtime 2012 installed. I installed everything. However, [I read in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html) that, an I quote:

> After customizing a windows instance, you need to run the EC2Config
>   service Sysprep. For information about EC2Config, go to Configuring a
>   Windows Instance Using the EC2Config Service.

Can someone please explain to me what exactly I should do. I can't understand it from the documentation. Thanks.

Running the instance on Windows Server 2012 / IIS8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used Ec2Config on Windows AMI sometime back to have my custom AMI generate a new password every time an Instance is launched from it.

However, there are quite a  few other things you can do with EC2Config on Windows AMI. Please refer the [documentation of EC2Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html) for more details.